# How can i uninstall Spagobi 4.2 and install SpagoBI 5.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, spagobi

i was working with SpagoBI 4.2 and i decided to pass on SpagoBI 5.1 without knowing the process. Now i installed both version 4.2 and 5.1 of SpagoBI and both don't working.

please assist me

Kind regards.

Comment: How do you know you have both versions 4.2 and 5.1 installed? Do you know where the 4.2 version is installed?

Answer (score 0):

1.First delete the old version of SpagoBI Sever 4.2 from your system.
2.then, install SpagoBI Server 5.1 tool  and set the
2.1 Environment path catalina home path like:- "C:\Program Files (x86)\All-In-One-SpagoBI-5.1-21012015"
2.2 tomcat_home path:- C:\Program Files (x86)\All-In-One-SpagoBI-5.1-21012015\lib
3.In cmd command execute the command SpagoBIStartup.bat.
4.And log in into browser.